# How to prevent a website overriding macOS keyboard shortcuts in Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I see a few threads on this for Firefox and Windows, but not for Chrome and Mac.

On macOS, for more than two decades, the keyboard shortcuts command-leftarrow and command-rightarrow have been offered to move the text cursor to the beginning or end of any text line. It is strongly imprinted into my muscle memory.

A website I need to use on the regular has overwritten this keyboard shortcut to an in-website action that navigates forward and backward, which causes me to lose all typed content.

How can I prevent this website (or all websites) from overriding this system keyboard shortcut (or all system shortcuts)?